# How can I view a directory as a tree in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, directory-listing

I would like to view my directories as trees, but not like they are shown on the left tab in Windows Explorer: there you just have the directories shown, while I also want their contents.

Furthermore, the tree you can get in Explorer can just start from the root directory (so it is always huge), while I would like it to start from wherever I want.

Basically I would like what is available in both Linux and MacOS...

Thank you!

Comment: The one useful feature of the Finder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If we would like to view **directories and files** on **the left sidebar** and view **the text** of one selected file on **the right sidebar** at the same time, some IDEs are good choices, for example, **[VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**.

[image: Screenshot]

[WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) can present a directories and files tree as same as TreeSize @Mehper C. Palavuzlar mentioned, too.

I'm wondering if there's a **better software** that **focuses on** presenting directories and files on the left sidebar like WinDirStat does and viewing various kinds of file on the right sidebar.